# 4 port 12 bit mux is consuming 48 macrocells!

Tags: verilog, xilinx, programmable-logic

I'm programming on the coolrunner II cpld. It is running out of resources so I decided to implement my own 4 port, 12 bit mux. After implementation I find that it's using over 40 macrocells. Any way to reduce this number? I've already tried using the optimization techniques with ISE XST, but it has not reduced the number. Here's my code

```
module mux_2to1_gates(a,b,sel,y);
input a,b,sel;
output y;

wire sel,a_sel,b_sel;

not U_inv (inv_sel,sel);
and U_anda (asel,a,inv_sel),
     U_andb (bsel,b,sel);
or U_or (y,asel,bsel);

endmodule    

module mux_four_to_one(a,b,c,d,sel,y);
input a,b,c,d;
input [1:0] sel;
output y;
integer i; 

wire mux_1,mux_2;

mux_2to1_gates U_mux1 (a,b,sel[0],mux_1),
                    U_mux2 (c,d,sel[0],mux_2),
                    U_mux3 (mux_1,mux_2,sel[1],y);

endmodule

module muxing( selecting, d1,d2,d3,d4, q );

input[1:0] selecting;
input[11:0] d1;
input[11:0] d2;
input[11:0] d3;
input[11:0] d4;
output[11:0] q;

genvar i;

generate 
    for(i=0; i < 12; i= i+1) begin: test
        mux_four_to_one named (d1[i],d2[i],d3[i],d4[i],selecting,q[i]);
    end
endgenerate



endmodule
```

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks for the feedback. Add your code as the answer and I'll accept it. I'm starting to think that it's the surrounding logic that is causing the huge increase of macro cell usage, so I'll post a different question for that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of implementing the mux as a gate-level logic, which may confuse the synthesizer, try to use some behavioral or RTL description, that will allow the synthesizer to choose the way to implement it optimally.  I am pretty sure the device has some built-in macrocells for implementing such a mux in minimal resources, that you are not aware of, but the software is. For example you can use the following code to infer the 12 bit 4-to-1 MUX:

```
module muxing( selecting, d1,d2,d3,d4, q );

input[1:0] selecting;
input[11:0] d1;
input[11:0] d2;
input[11:0] d3;
input[11:0] d4;
output[11:0] q;

wire [11:0] d[3:0];

assign d[0] = d1;
assign d[1] = d2;
assign d[2] = d3;
assign d[3] = d4;

assign q = d[selecting];

endmodule
```

As a side note - both implementations, the given in the question, and the proposed one resulted in 12 macrocells usage when tested on my machine (Xilinx ISE 14.1).